# Is it possible to do bitshift operations on a character in PHP

Tags: php, char, bit-manipulation

In the code like this:

```
<?php

$a = 'абв';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++)
{
        echo $a[$i]>>6, ' ';
}
```

The output is `0 0 0 0 0 0`, which is not what is expected. The expected output is values 3 and 2, depending on whether we are in a beginning or the end of the UTF-8 character.

What is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although PHP provides many functions that are a simply wrapper around their C counterparts, the developers have decided to add an extra check to the bit shift operators. In PHP shift-left and shift-right always return 0 (not even false, which would make some sense).

In order to bit-shift a character, it is necessary to wrap it with `ord` function:

```
<?php

$a = 'абв';

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++)
{
        echo ord($a[$i])>>6, ' ';
}
```

This produces: `3 2 3 2 3 2` as expected.